# Using Ghostscript 9.07 -dUseCropBox how to enable the crop box

Tags: ghostscript

Ghostscript Version : 9.07

To achieve Crop Box : Not able to enable crop box

So far tried : PS to PDF and PDF to PDF(both are unsuccessful)

Command :

```
gs -dPDFX -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dUseCropBox -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=GS_test.pdf PDFX_def.ps test.ps

gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dUseCropBox -sOutputFile=cropbox.pdf GS_test.pdf
```

Both the output is not enable the crop box. Please help me out.

Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by 'enable crop box' ? If the input file is PostScript then there won't be a CropBox. You can create a PDF file which contains a CropBox from PostScript by using pdfmark. If the input is PDF then the input may, or may not, include a CropBox. If ti does, then it will be preserved in the PDF output.

What exactly are you expecting to happen ?

Comment: When executing the above command Ps to PDF it was generated without the Crop box. Could you please give me any information to have the crop box for the PDF file. Now I can achieve the Media Box, Trim Box and Art box but Crop Box was missing.